# Pycharm - Error installing libraries

Tags: python, pycharm

I was trying to install `sklearn` in Pycharm and encountered this error

[image]

Last time I encountered this error, I update `pip` using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` in the command line and the installation worked. But this time it is already up to date.

Really appreciate any help about what I should to to install packages in PyCharm
[image]

Comment: On SO it is strongly preferred to post copied text instead of screenshots. Also, the error message contains the root of the problem and even a link to instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you don't have *SciPy* installed which is probably required for *sklearn* library to work.

Is *SciPy* installed in your system or is it broken?

Try installing(or reinstalling) that first from https://scipy.org/install.html